# How to throw exception from spring batch processor process() method to Spring batch job started method?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-batch

I am having the Web-service method to start spring batch job.If any exception occurred in spring batch processing control is coming back till processor process method. But i need the controller to came back to web-service method there i have to catch and code to email that exception.

Web-service method:

```
public void processInputFiles() throws ServiceFault {

    String[] springConfig = { CONTEXT_FILE_NAME };

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
    try {
        setClientInfo();

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean(JOB_LAUNCHER);
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean(REMITTANCE_JOB);

        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = "LockboxService exception:: Could not process Remittance(CSV) files";
        final Message message = MessageFactory.createErrorMessage(MyService.class, errorMessage, e);
        ErrorSenderFactory.getInstance().send(message, new Instruction[] { Instruction.ERROR_EMAIL });

    }
```

Processor process method:

```
@Override
public Transmission process(InputDetail remrow) throws ServiceException {
  try {
    business logic here
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Unable to process row having the int number:");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is startJob which I use the to start the job in web application, Tye to throw specific exception

```
public boolean StartJob()
            throws MyException{



        try {

                final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addLong("time", System.nanoTime())
                        .addString("file", jobInputFolder.getAbsolutePath())
                        .toJobParameters();

                final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,
                        jobParameters);
                final ExitStatus status = execution.getExitStatus();

                if (ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode().equals(
                        status.getExitCode())) {
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    final List<Throwable> exceptions = execution
                            .getAllFailureExceptions();
                    for (final Throwable throwable : exceptions) {

                        if (throwable instanceof MyException) {
                            throw (MyException) throwable;
                        }
                        if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) {

                            Throwable rootException = throwable.getCause();
                            if (rootException instanceof IncorrectTokenCountException) {

                                throw new MyException(logMessage, errorCode);
                            }
                            if (rootException instanceof BindException) {
                                BindException bindException = (BindException) rootException;
                                final FieldError fieldError = bindException
                                        .getFieldError();
                                final String field = fieldError.getField();

                                throw new MyException(logMessage, errorCode);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException ex) {

        } catch (JobRestartException ex) {

        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException ex) {

        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } finally {

        }

        return result;
    }
```

If Item processor is as below

```
@Override
public KPData process(InputDetail inputData) throws MyException {
  try {
    business logic here
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    throw new MyException("Some issue");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, it actually solved my problem. I didn't know the capturing all exception using the getAllFailureExceptions(); method.