# Batch job fails because of JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

How to stop batch job from the main method ? I am running the batch job from my method and now its giving me the below error. Any help on how to kill and stop it?

```
A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=18380, version=0, Job=[myFileGenerationJob]
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=18380, version=0, Job=[myFileGenerationJob]
Done
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.CustomerFileGenerationApp.main(CustomerFileGenerationApp.java:31)
```

I am using the following code -

```
public class CustomerFileGenerationApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
        String[] springConfig = { "../META-INF/spring/customer-file-generation-job.xml"};

        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("customerFileGenerationJob");

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("runMode", "ABCD").toJobParameters();

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch and JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809057/spring-batch-and-jobinstancealreadycompleteexception)

Comment: Is there any way we can kill that already running job? I know already the JobInstance: id=18380.

Comment: AFAIK using Spring batch admin

Comment: Ok. Is there any workaround of killing using command line or from DB ? I dont have batch Admin UI. I did not find out any way to kill JobInstance Id. looks strange to me. Any further guidance ?

Comment: Not from me, sorry! Maybe later someone will partecipate to discussion

Comment: Linux or Window? Find java process and kill it

Comment: I am using windows box

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I have no idea to deal with that Exception by using java code.
But, You can manage that exception by updating related batch meta table datas by using some queries.

There are two tables you should check,
batch_step_execution, batch_job_execution.
(I assume that you create them already because the Spring Batch provides them to almost all kind of database.)

If those tables has a started(starting) and not completed job,
You can encounter the exception above when you restart server.

So first, you can check whether running jobs exist by executing queries below.

```
SELECT  STEP_EXECUTION_ID
        , JOB_EXECUTION_ID
        , STEP_NAME
        , STATUS
        , EXIT_CODE
        , bse.*
FROM batch_step_execution bse
WHERE 1=1
AND status IN ('STARTED', 'STARTING')
AND exit_code NOT IN ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED')
ORDER BY start_time desc
;

SELECT bje.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
        , bji.JOB_NAME
        , bje.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
        , bje.STATUS
        , bje.EXIT_CODE
        , timediff(bje.CREATE_TIME, NOW()) 
        , bje.*
FROM batch_job_execution bje
INNER JOIN batch_job_instance bji
ON bje.job_instance_id = bji.job_instance_id
WHERE 1=1
AND status IN ('STARTED', 'STARTING')
AND exit_code NOT IN ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED')
ORDER BY bje.create_time desc
;
```

Second, if there are rows above,
You can update those jobs to COMPLETED status by executing queries below.

```
UPDATE 
    batch_step_execution 
SET END_TIME = now()
    ,LAST_UPDATED = now() 
    ,STATUS = 'COMPLETED' 
    ,EXIT_CODE = 'FAILED' 
WHERE 
    STEP_EXECUTION_ID in (
        select STEP_EXECUTION_ID 
        from batch_step_execution bse 
        where 1=1
        and status not in ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED')
        or EXIT_CODE not in ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED') 
    )
;

UPDATE 
    BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION 
SET 
    END_TIME = now() 
    ,LAST_UPDATED = now() 
    ,STATUS = 'COMPLETED' 
    ,EXIT_CODE = 'FAILED' 
WHERE 
   JOB_EXECUTION_ID in (
        select bje.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
        from batch_job_execution bje 
        where 1=1
        and (status not in ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED'))
        or (EXIT_CODE not in ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED'))
   )
;
```

Third, please restart the server.
In my case, it works when I encounter the JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException.

Thanks.