# Why a business' catch block does not catch a Spring Batch exception?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am working with `Spring Batch` 3.0.7

I have the following code:

```
    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    try{
        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        logger.info("jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode(): {}", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        logger.error("Throwable: {}", t.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.error("{}", t.getMessage());
        logger.info("jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode(): {}", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
```

Due an experiment scenario the `Job` executed must fail when the `ItemProcessor` process a specific record, thus a customized exception (PersonBatchException) is thrown:

```
44207 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.1.8] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step one in job simpleDatabaseJdbcReaderErrorProcessorDatabaseJdbcWriter 
com.manuel.jordan.batch.exception.PersonBatchException: The record 999 has been selected to fail
    at com.manuel.jordan.batch.processor.PersonExceptionItemProcessor.process(PersonExceptionItemProcessor.java:36)
```

In this case the `catch` block should work, but it is never executed.

Of course the Console prints all the **error** stack trace how shown above.

Even if `<skippable-exception-classes>` would be used, lets assume an exception thrown would be arised but is not listed in the section mentioned.

Let's assume the `jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)` is called through either a `JMX` or special `@Service` process

How handle this?

**Alpha**

```
public class PersonBatchException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7424725101950190824L;

    public PersonBatchException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: What code is at PersonExceptionItemProcessor.java:36?

Comment: Pls see _Alpha_ section.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441722/3665178

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post:

- [How to throw exception from spring batch processor process() method
  to Spring batch job started method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571225/how-to-throw-exception-from-spring-batch-processor-process-method-to-spring-ba)

I have this version:

```
    JobExecution jobExecution = null;

    try{
        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        logger.info("Try jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode(): {}", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
    catch(RuntimeException re){
        logger.error("NEVER NEVER EXECUTED NEVER NEVER");
        logger.error("RuntimeException Class: {}", re.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.error("{}", re.getMessage());
        logger.error("Catch jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode(): {}", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

    if(jobExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED)) {
        List<Throwable> exceptions = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
        for(Throwable throwable : exceptions){
            logger.error("Throwable Class: {}", throwable.getClass().getSimpleName());
            logger.error("{}", throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The `catch` block **never** work, but through the `for` block is possible do practically the same how the `catch` block.

Seems `Spring Batch`'s internal process works in some way that reflects this behavior to the `catch` block